# How to verify element uniqueness in appium

Tags: java, appium

I am transitioning from web-ui automation and trying to figure if there's a way to figure out whether an element that I want to use is going to work.
E.g. with selenium I can go to Chrome devtools and type something like

```
$$("#uniqueid")
```

and it will show me whether this is actually a unique id.

With appium I find it hard to understand when to use an id or text or something else.

Answer (score 0):

You can use search for element option in appium desktop which will give you all the matching element corresponding to that id or whichever selector you want.